# how to add an item to registry to run at startup without UAC

Tags: batch-file, registry, startup, uac

i have a program that needs to be started when windows starts. I have created a string value in registry `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run\`
For this application starts at startup but it shows an UAC prompt. Normally my application does not need UAC promt to start. If i make a shortcut in startup folder then it works perfectly without UAC but the the problem is i need to start it from registry. and sorry that i also cannot use task scheduler. Do anyone have an idea how to do it?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can always start it for a single user, this command can be run by a normal user, and will enable the application on startup for just that user.

```
REG ADD "HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run" /V "My App" /t REG_SZ /F /D "C:\MyAppPath\MyApp.exe"
```

You cannot add something to the local machine run registry key without at some point running something as Administrator.

Even task scheduler option would require something to run as admin to add the task in.

Comment: that didn't worked. its also asking for administrator permission.

Comment: wierd, I'll give it a test in a bit, make sure you are using "HKCU\Software", not "HKLM\Software"

Comment: sorry for what i commented before. it worked.thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had trouble finding the registry entry for the user created afterwards so I also did

```
wmic useraccount where (name='user.user') get name,sid
```

or

```
reg query HKU
```

then

```
reg query HKU\SID\software\Microsoft\Windows\Currentversion\Run /v "MyApp"
```

in order to delete

```
reg delete HKU\SID\software\Microsoft\Windows\Currentversion\Run /v "MyApp" /f
```